# Envio variable de una página a otra mediante GET por el Location PHP

Tags: php

Tengo dos páginas en php:

- adivina.php
- procesa.php

Tengo que introducir un valor en el formulario, compararlo aleatoriamente y publicar una pista al usuario si tiene que subir o bajar el número en el próximo intento intente acercar (esta acotado del 1 al 100), mi problema es quiero que la variable $contador que se incrementa en procesa.php viaje por el Location pero solo me imprime el propio nombre de la variable y no su valor (que con cada fallo aumenta de valor). Otra parte del ejercicio me pide tanto si aciertas como si agotas los cinco intentos, el programa debe "ocultar el formulario" cosa que no se me ocurre como ocultarlo porque es un formulario html, intenté meter el formulario dentro de una variable de php pero me daba problemas con el campo hidden. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>adivina.php</h2>
  <form name="formulario1" action="procesa.php" method="GET" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <label for='leyenda'>Introduce un numero entre 1 y 100</label>
    <input type='number' min='0' max='100' name='numero' required autofocus>
    <!-- Campo oculto -->
    <input type="hidden" name="contador" value="contador">

    <input type='submit' name='enviar1' value='Enviar1'>
    <input type='reset' value='Restablecer'>
  </form>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['solucion'])){
  if($_GET['solucion']=="acertaste"){
    echo "<p>has acertado</p>";
  } else if($_GET['solucion']=="sube"){
    $variable = $_GET['contador'];
    echo "<p>sube</p>";
    echo $variable;
  } else if($_GET['solucion']=="baja"){
    echo "<p>baja</p>";
  }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<h2>procesa.php</h2>
<?php
$acertar=rand(1,100);
$contador=0;
if(isset($_GET['enviar1'])){
  if(($_GET['numero']==$acertar)){
    header('Location:adivina.php?solucion=acertaste');
  } else if(($_GET['numero']<$acertar)){
    $contador++;
    header('Location:adivina.php?solucion=sube&contador=$contador');
  } else {
    $contador++;
    header('Location:adivina.php?solucion=baja&contador=$contador');
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes usar Javascript y Ajax o Fetch para este ejercicio o te piden de hacerlo todo en PHP?

Comment: me lo piden en PHP

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema parece estar en la redireccion:

```
header('Location:adivina.php?solucion=sube&contador=$contador');
```

En PHP cuando usas comillas simples los nombres de variables no se "expanden" (es decir, llenan su valor con el valor de la variable), debes usar comillas dobles para que su valor sea reemplazado. Cambia los llamados a header por comillas dobles así:

```
header("Location:adivina.php?solucion=sube&contador=$contador");
```

Comment: Era ese el problema, muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido mi solución. Considera marcar la respuesta como "aceptada" para así ayudar a toda la comunidad. Saludos.